# R + knitr + PerformanceAnalytics plotting errors

Tags: r, plot, xts, knitr, performanceanalytics

I am running the following bit of code but for some reason when using `charts.PerformanceSummary()` inside a `for` loop it tries to make more outputs than the number of times it goes through the loop. Whereas a simple plot function seems to work fine...

Please see the .Rmd code below and then the subsequent .md file created after kniting to html...

````
PLOT TEST
====

```{r}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(PerformanceAnalytics))
for(i in 1:5){
  charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(rnorm(i*1000,0.0001,0.0003),Sys.Date()-c((i*1000):1)))
}
```

```{r}
for(i in 1:5){
  plot(xts(cumprod(rnorm(i*1000,0.0001,0.0003)+1),Sys.Date()-c((i*1000):1)))
}
```
````

Giving the following .md file

````
PLOT TEST
====


```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(PerformanceAnalytics))
for (i in 1:5) {
    charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(rnorm(i * 1000, 1e-04, 3e-04), Sys.Date() - 
   c((i * 1000):1)))
}
```

![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-1](figure/unnamed-chunk-11.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-1](figure/unnamed-chunk-12.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-1](figure/unnamed-chunk-13.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-1](figure/unnamed-chunk-14.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-1](figure/unnamed-chunk-15.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-1](figure/unnamed-chunk-16.png) 



```r
for (i in 1:5) {
    plot(xts(cumprod(rnorm(i * 1000, 1e-04, 3e-04) + 1), Sys.Date() - c((i * 
    1000):1)))
}
```

![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2](figure/unnamed-chunk-21.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2](figure/unnamed-chunk-22.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2](figure/unnamed-chunk-23.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2](figure/unnamed-chunk-24.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2](figure/unnamed-chunk-25.png)
````

Notice how there are 6 output plots that the frist chunk tries to connect to but there are only 5 output plots in the second chunk despite both having the same `for (i in 1:5) {` bit of code...

As additional information the below was the `sessionInfo`

```
sessionInfo() 
## R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
## Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
## [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.1.0 xts_0.9-3                 
## [3] zoo_1.7-9                  knitr_1.2                 
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] digest_0.6.3    evaluate_0.4.3  formatR_0.7     grid_3.0.0     
## [5] lattice_0.20-15 stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.0.0
```

*EDIT*

I have also just run the one line it on its own, and have a semi-fix...but not one for doing multiple charts in the same chunk...

Below is the .Rmd script together with the .md output

````
```{r}
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(rnorm(1000,0.0001,0.0003),Sys.Date()-c((1000):1)))
```

```{r fig.keep='last'}
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(rnorm(1000,0.0001,0.0003),Sys.Date()-c((1000):1)))
```
````

the .md output

````
```r
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(rnorm(1000, 1e-04, 3e-04), Sys.Date() - c((1000):1)))
```

![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-4](figure/unnamed-chunk-41.png) ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-4](figure/unnamed-chunk-42.png) 



```r
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(rnorm(1000, 1e-04, 3e-04), Sys.Date() - c((1000):1)))
```

![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-5](figure/unnamed-chunk-5.png)
````

*EDIT  2*

As pointed out by @agstudy it looks like knitr is producing an unnecessary blank image...does anybody know how to remove it?

Comment: I think it is just creating a bank picture!,,,,,

Comment: I think so too...but I would rather it didn't...Any ideas of how to get rid of it?

Comment: for blank images, it is a known problem; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/16648872/559676